# E/Volley﹕ [94] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for (GET)

Tags: android, image, android-volley

Does anyone have the simplest way to bypass this error? I'm trying to get images from an api, and some images aren't just null; they do have a link, that redirects to a XML Error page when you click on it: that says

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<Error>
 <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
 <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
 <Key>
  uploads/screen_medium/8/82063/2639956-0786a819b3e03ae2cba563a3c32130c8_large.jpg
 </Key>
 <RequestId>2C3C1F784F3903E6</RequestId>
 <HostId>
  wf6PCjKgSLjENlno8ydKk6rfhCdYTIRQayuREgA9ox7KhfHqaPvb43qCJTZYUsZw
 </HostId>
</Error>
```

Do I need to utilize the Volley ImageLoader onErrorResponse in my RecyclerView's adapter?

```
if (iconUrl != null){
        mImageLoader.get(iconUrl, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                Drawable image = new BitmapDrawable(response.getBitmap());
                image.setAlpha(100);
                viewHolderUpcoming.mLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(image);
            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //default image 
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give the proper URL link... 
For example:
My url is = http://www.imply.com/kf/webservices/

but, I missed the  final forward slash like "http://www.imply.com/kf/webservices" , that's the problem.. i faced like that problem